What is REAL story behind Venkateshwara Temple (Tirupati Balaji)?
A lot of people give a lot of completely contradicting tales as the origins of the highly esteemed Venkateshwara Temple. Some of them to be honest sound ridiculous.
One was that Vishnu took form of Srinivasa and married Padmavati, one day Lakshmi came to him and upon seeing Padmavati and Lakshmi together Vishnu turned to a stone idol. This seems either incomplete or just wrong. Vishnu came on earth to find Lakshmi Maa and ended up marrying somebody else? And he turned to stone upon being confronted? I’m sure this is a false version of the actual story.
Please enlighten me with the real tale and cite your responses. Thank You!

Real story means what? Without supernatural elements?

@estimator I meant the original one, or the most accepted one, one which doesn't downplay Narayana's intelligence.

You have already mentioned the most accepted one. As to how it downplays the intelligence of Narayana, it is not clear to me.

Came down to earth to find his dear wife Lakshmi, ends up marrying Padmavati and turns to stone when confronted by Lakshmi Maa, this sounds like a Sony Sab comedy sketch man, how can this be the legend behind one of the most important temples? I highly doubt the story matches with what is written in the puranas.

This is sthala puranam, it may or may not be found in puranas. There are 1000s of such sthala puranas for various temples. Padmavati is supposed to be Vedavati in a previous incarnation.

@estimator Vedavati took birth as Sita later on, and the concept of 'maya Sita' is not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana.

Yes, even Aditya Hrudayam is not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana. Rama worshipping Shiva is not mentioned. But these became popular later on.

Read Venkatachala Mahatmya of Vaishnava khanda in Skanda Purana.
